# Does Spark Sql executions use thread local jobgroup?

Tags: apache-spark

From my findings running multiple sparksqls with different job groups does not put them in the specified groups. 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29340

Creating new threadlocal jobgroup works for spark dataframe jobs but not for sparksql. Is there a way to put all threadlocal spark sql executions in a separate jobgroup?

```
val sparkThreadLocal: SparkSession = DataCurator.spark.newSession()

sparkThreadLocal.sparkContext.setJobGroup("<id>", "<description>")

OR

sparkThreadLocal.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.job.description", "<id>")
sparkThreadLocal.sparkContext.setLocalProperty("spark.jobGroup.id", "<description>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved! It was an issue with using scala parallel iteration, which uses threadpools.